# Stacking ensemble with two different inputs for image segmenatation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I an stacking two models trained on different inputs from two data collections as shown below using Tensorflow Keras 2.6.2. The stacking is performed with a convolutional meta-learner to predict on a common hold out test set. Given below is the code and he model architecture.

[image]

```
#load data

#datase-1
X_tr1 = np.load('data/X_tr1.npy') #shape (200, 224,224,3)
Y_tr1 = np.load('data/Y_tr1.npy') #shape (200, 224,224,1)
X_val1 = np.load('data/X_val1.npy') #shape (100, 224,224,3)
Y_val1 = np.load('data/Y_val1.npy') #shape (100, 224,224,1)

#dataset-2
X_tr2 = np.load('data/X_tr2.npy') #shape (200, 224,224,3)
Y_tr2 = np.load('data/Y_tr2.npy') #shape (200, 224,224,1)
X_val2 = np.load('data/X_val2.npy') #shape (100, 224,224,3)
Y_val2 = np.load('data/Y_val2.npy') #shape (100, 224,224,1)

#common hold-out test set
X_ts = np.load('data/X_ts.npy') #shape (50, 224,224,3)
Y_ts = np.load('data/Y_ts.npy') #shape (50, 224,224,1)

#%%
#instantiate the models
img_width, img_height = 224,224
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3) #RGB inputs
model_input1 = Input(shape=input_shape) #input to model1
model_input2 = Input(shape=input_shape) #input to model2
n_classes=1  #grayscale mask output
activation='sigmoid' 
batch_size = 8
n_epochs = 256

BACKBONE = 'vgg16'

# define model
model1 = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet', 
                  classes=n_classes, activation=activation)
model2 = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet', 
                  classes=n_classes, activation=activation)
#%%
# constructing a stacking ensemble of the two models
# A second-level fully-convolutional meta-learner is used to learn 
# the features extracted from the penultimate layers of the models

n_models = 2 

def load_all_models(n_models):
    all_models = list()    
    model1.load_weights('weights/vgg16_1.hdf5') # path to model1
    model_loss1a=Model(inputs=model1.input,
                        outputs=model1.get_layer('decoder_stage4b_relu').output) #name of the penultimate layer
    x1 = model_loss1a.output
    model1a = Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=x1, name='model1')
    all_models.append(model1a)
    model2.load_weights('weights/vgg16_2.hdf5') #path to model2
    model_loss2a=Model(inputs=model2.input,
                        outputs=model2.get_layer('decoder_stage4b_relu').output) 
    x2 = model_loss2a.output
    model2a = Model(inputs=model2.input, outputs=x2, name='model2')
    all_models.append(model2a)    
    return all_models

# load models
n_members = 2
members = load_all_models(n_members)
print('Loaded %d models' % len(members))


def define_stacked_model(members):
    # update all layers in all models to not be trainable
    for i in range(len(members)):
        model = members[i]
        for layer in model.layers [1:]:
        # make not trainable
            layer.trainable = False    
            layer._name = 'ensemble_' + str(i+1) + '_' + layer.name
    ensemble_outputs = [model(model_input1, model_input2) for model in members]    
    merge = Concatenate()(ensemble_outputs)
    # meta-learner, fully-convolutional 
    x4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', 
                name = 'NewConv1', padding='same')(merge)
    x5 = Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation='sigmoid', 
                name = 'NewConvfinal')(x4)
    model= Model(inputs=[model_input1,model_input2], 
                  outputs=x4)
    return model
    

print("Creating Ensemble")
ensemble = define_stacked_model(members)
print("Ensemble architecture: ")
print(ensemble.summary())
```

Shown below is the architecture of the stacked model:

```
Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model1 (Functional)             (None, None, None, 1 23752128    input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model2 (Functional)             (None, None, None, 1 23752128    input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 224, 224, 32) 0           model1[0][0]                     
                                                                 model2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
NewConv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 128 36992       concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
NewConv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 64) 73792       NewConv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
NewConv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 32) 18464       NewConv2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
NewConvfinal (Conv2D)           (None, 224, 224, 1)  33          NewConv3[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 47,633,537
Trainable params: 129,281
Non-trainable params: 47,504,256
```

I compile and train the model as shown below:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
loss_func='binary_crossentropy'
ensemble.compile(optimizer=opt, 
              loss=loss_func, 
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

results_ensemble = ensemble.fit((X_tr1, Y_tr1, X_tr2, Y_tr2),
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    epochs=n_epochs, 
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(X_val1, Y_val1, X_val2, Y_val2))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/codes/untitled5.py", line 563, in <module>
    validation_data=(X_val1, Y_val1, X_val2, Y_val2))

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tf262/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1125, in fit
    data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tf262/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1574, in unpack_x_y_sample_weight
    raise ValueError(error_msg)

ValueError: Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`, or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: (array([[[[0.09803922, 0.09803922, 0.09803922],
         [0.09803922, 0.09803922, 0.09803922],
         [0.09803922, 0.09803922, 0.09803922],
         ...,
         [0.08627451, 0.08627451, 0.08627451],
         [0.08627451, 0.08627451, 0.08627451],
         [0.05098039, 0.05098039, 0.05098039]],...
```

Also how do I predict with a single X_ts provided the ensemble model now has two separate inputs?

New error after trying to implement the suggestions:

```
File "/home/codes/untitled5.py", line 595, in <module>
    validation_data=outputs)

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tf262/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1184, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)

    ValueError: Layer model_4 expects 2 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 224, 224, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(None, 224, 224, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: Ensemble inputs need to be passed to the `.fit()` method as a list, not a tuple. If you want to pass a single input element for a multi-input model, you just copy the single element as many times as you need. e.g. for a 3-input ensemble with input `x`, the x parameter of `.fit()` or `.predict()` would be `x=[x, x, x]` and `y` would need to match when training and evaluating. Passing a tuple as an input is only for `Dataset` or `Sequence`, not arrays. If you want to to tuples with an ensemble, you'd need a list of tuples, not just tuples.

Comment: @Djinn I would be able to accept the answer if you can post the code correction. Thanks.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer based on comment. Multi-inputs need to be passed as a list, not a tuple.

Change:

```
results_ensemble = ensemble.fit((X_tr1, Y_tr1, X_tr2, Y_tr2),
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    epochs=n_epochs, 
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(X_val1, Y_val1, X_val2, Y_val2))
```

To:

```
inputs = [X_tr1, Y_tr1, X_tr2, Y_tr2]  # you can pass the list itself or the variable
results_ensemble = ensemble.fit(inputs,
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    epochs=n_epochs, 
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=([X_val1, X_val2], y_val))

# test_inputs_diff = [x_test1, x_test2]  # different input
# test_inputs_same = [x_test1, x_test1]  # same input
# preds_diff = ensemble.predict(test_inputs_diff)
# preds_same = ensemble.predict(test_inputs_same)
```

Comment: I have to follow the list strategy to the validation data as well, so I did, outputs = [X_val1, Y_val1, X_val2, Y_val2] and then passed 'validation_data=outputs'. But running the code after these corrections gave way to a new error, which I have mentioned in my edits uder "New error after trying to implement the suggestions". Looking forward to your assistance. Thanks.

Comment: The parameter `validation_data` must receive either a 2-tuple containing `features, labels` or a 3-tuple containing `features, labels, sample_weights`. I haven't done much with this parameter and multi-inputs specifically but maybe the `x-` and `y-` parameters should be a tuple of lists. It can't accept a 4-tuple like above. For example, `([x0, x1, ..., xn-1], [y0, y1, ..., yn-1])`.

Comment: You could also maybe try making a `Dataset` object and pass that.

Comment: Correction: `([x0, x1, ..., xn-1], y)` Answer updated.^